# On the `exec FD>` form of exec

Tags: shell, zsh, io-redirection

I cannot find anything in the `zsh` man page explaining exactly what the following (for example) does

```
exec 3> /tmp/foo
```

All the proper documentation I can find for `exec` refers to the form in which `exec` is followed by a "simple command".  (E.g. see [`man zshbuiltins`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins), and [`man zshmisc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshmisc).)  (The `exec FD>` form is mentioned briefly in [`man zshmisc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshmisc), but in a passage that looks to me assumes that this form has been fully and properly documented elsewhere.)

I looked at all the hits produced by

```
man zshall | grep -P '\bexec\b'
```

...but none were what I was looking for.

Does someone know of a good substitute for the missing documentation?

---

PS: A possible explanation for what looks to me like "missing documentation" is that forms like `exec 3> /tmp/foo` are in fact special cases of the form "`exec` *simple command*".  If this is so, however, then I would like to find documentation that explains (1) how, e.g., `3> /tmp/foo` is a simple command (if I run this "simple command" on the command line, it just hangs until I hit `^C`); and (2) why code in a script happening after something like `exec 3> /tmp/foo` gets evaluated, whereas that happening after, say, `exec date` doesn't.

Comment: You may want to read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20, also, `zshall` does have mention it in builtin section: `If command is omitted but any redirections are specified, then the redirections will take effect in the current shell.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meanings of `exec` with and without a command are unrelated. I guess the builtin name is overloaded because one meaning doesn't make sense with a command and the other doesn't make sense without a command, so doing it this way saved having to invent a new name that would then not be usable for another command.

The [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-exec) states:

> If *command* is omitted but any redirections are specified, then the redirections will take effect in the current shell.

What this means is that something like `exec 3> /tmp/foo` changes what file descriptor 3 points to in the running shell process. A shell snippet like `/bin/somecommand 3>/tmp/foo` means the following:

1. Create a subprocess.
2. Open `/tmp/foo` for writing on file descriptor 3 in the subprocess.
3. Execute the file `/bin/somecommand` in the subprocess.

`exec 3>/tmp/foo` just performs step 3, it doesn't do anything about processes.

After `exec 3>/tmp/foo`, all subsequent accesses to file descriptor 3 from the shell and its subprocesses go to `/tmp/foo`, like with any other redirection. For example, suppose you run the following script in a terminal with nothing connected to file descriptor 3:

```
echo hello           # prints to the terminal
echo nope >&3        # complains about a bad descriptor since no file is open on fd 3
exec >/tmp/out 3>/tmp/three
echo hello           # writes to /tmp/out
echo howdy >&3       # writes to /tmp/three
echo wibble >&3      # writes a second line to /tmp/three
```

Comment: It's related in that `exec` means _not fork_. `exec cmd > foo`  does the redirection and execs `cmd` in the current shell process. `exec > foo` still does the redirection in the current process but doesn't execute anything.